# Getting errors while providing rabbitMQ configuration in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

**Error** :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/MessageConverter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)

**RabbitConfig.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
    public class RabbitMQConfig {
    @Value("${javainuse.rabbitmq.queue}")
    String queueName;

    @Value("${javainuse.rabbitmq.exchange}")
    String exchange;

    @Value("${javainuse.rabbitmq.routingkey}")
    private String routingkey;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){

        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new CachingConnectionFactory("127.0.0.1");
        connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
        connectionFactory.setPort(5672);
        connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
        return connectionFactory;

    }

    @Bean
    DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingkey);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Pom.xml:**:   Dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>queue-service</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.hp.oo.unifiedcommons</groupId>
        <version>2020.05.0.47-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>queue-service-impls</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hp.oo.unifiedcommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>oo-outbox-mapper-api</artifactId>
            <version>2020.05.0.47-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


</project>
```

I am not sure but is it because of spring version ??. I mean sometimes i am getting error in **ConnectionFactory** function or sometimes i got error in **MessageConvertor** function that I am using in my **RabbitMQConfig.java** .

Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Comment: How are you building and running your application? JAR or WAR? Running from the terminal or in an IDE?

Comment: as per my understanding, you may have a conflict in your libraries that are loaded at runtime - check your mvn dependency tree. ur might not see the error in ur IDE since the IDE might be loading the correct library - but when ur deploying it - it might be a case of a different conflicting library getting loaded. For example, you may have a different dependency to a rabbitmq apart from the "spring-boot-starter-amqp" dependency. You may have to resolve the conflicts by adding "exclusions" in your pom.xml wherever necessary or remove conflicts dependencies altogether. good luck!

Comment: While building it was successful but after that it shows error in wrapper.log file.

Comment: @code_kbd I actually got your point and i add one more dependency but now i am getting error in ConnectionFactory method in RabbitMQCongig.java. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.amqp/spring-amqp

Comment: instead of adding dependencies, you should first analyse the conflicting dependencies is my take on this.

Comment: In addition to this, its better to post the spring versions that u have used. not only the spring version for spring-amqp but also versions of other dependencies that help other readers to assist - with what u have provided it will be difficult for anyone to suggest what the issue may be. maybe edit ur post with other dependencies and their versions.

Comment: @code_kbd .I have include the complete pom.xml file.

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace.
>`<version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>`
Why are you overriding Boot's version of that jar?  You should also override spring-rabbit for compatibility.
What version of Spring Boot is the parent pom using? It might not be compatible with that version of spring-amqp.

Comment: @shikari - u have not given all the dependencies since u have a parent pom. Im pretty sure you have different set of versions that u have defined on the parent pom file. Refer to Gary's message above.
In addition to this, you may  use "mvn dependency:tree" command and check if there are conflicting libraries as well. Refer https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html.

Comment: Find out thanks bro it worked !!!